# How to get current financial year quarter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get current financial year quarter in SQL Server?

For instance if the this is the fourth financial year quarter (Jan, Feb, March) then I need to display `Quarter4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  'Quarter '+CAST(DATEPART(Q,DATEADD(MM,-3,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) AS QUARTER
```